# json.decoder.JSONDecodeError Error while calling a json file in python3

Tags: json, python-3.x

I'M just playing around to the CISCO switch device using netmiko module and having my credentials like IP address, password , user name in a json file and calling that json file into the python script to get these details.. while executing this i'm getting ad error, i have given the details below, please suggest what i'm doing wrong ...

```
$ cat CiscoNet_6.py
#!/usr/bin/python3
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function
import netmiko
import paramiko
import json
######################################
## JSON: Javascript object Notation ##
######################################
# creating a tuple
netmiko_exceptions = (netmiko.ssh_exception.NetMikoAuthenticationException,
                              netmiko.ssh_exception.NetMikoTimeoutException)

with open('devices.json') as dev_file:
    devices = json.load(dev_file)

for device in devices:
    try:
        print('-'*79)
        print('Net Device Address Is: -->', device['ip'])
        #print('Net Device Address Is: -->', device)
        connection = netmiko.ConnectHandler(**device)
        print(connection.send_command('show clock'))
        print('-'*79)
        connection.disconnect()
    except netmiko_exceptions as e:
        #print('Authentication failed to', 'Device')
        print('Failed to', device['ip'], e)
        #print('Failed to', device, e)
```

My JSON File `devices.json`:

```
[
 {
  "ip: "192.168.0.200",
  "device_type": "cisco_ios",
  "username": "nettest",
  "password": "cisco123"
 }
]
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./CiscoNet_6.py", line 18, in <module>
    devices = json.load(dev_file)
  File "/python/v3.6.1/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 299, in load
    parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)
  File "/python/v3.6.1/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/python/v3.6.1/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/python/v3.6.1/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 3 column 3 (char 7)
```

Comment: sorry guys, there was a issue in my json file formating which i have corrected now.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this is why

```
"ip*"*: "192.168.0.200",
```

Comment: dcluo, yes, somehow i missed double quote closure  around `"ip"`